# how can i send an object from one function to another function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and Javascript. I tried to send an object from one function to another function

**HTML Code:**

```
<div ng-click="getValueFromHtml(userObj)">send Object </div>
```

**Controller Code:**

```
$scope.getValueFromHtml=function(userObj){
console.log(JSON.stringify(userObj)); //here userObj coming from html
}

$scope.getUserObj=function(userObj){
console.log(userObj) //here i want to use userObj
}
```

Comment: What is `userObj` ?

Comment: How are you trying to access `$scope.getUserObj`?

Comment: You can just call $scope.getUserObj inside your getValueFromHtml like this 

`$scope.getValueFromHtml=function(userObj){
console.log(JSON.stringify(userObj)); //here userObj coming from html
$scope.getUserObj(userObj);
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can stored the `userObj` in local to the controller.

```
.controller('testCtrl',function(){

    var objUser = null;
    scope.getValueFromHtml=function(userObj){
        objUser = userObj;
    }

    $scope.getUserObj=function(userObj){
        console.log(objUser) //here i want to use userObj
    }
})
```

In the future,if you want to share this one across app,

you can stored it using [`services/factory`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services).